# How to initialise CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation with previousServerchangetoken?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, objective-c-blocks, cloudkit

I am fetching record changes from CloudKit Server but each time I get error

> [LogFacilityCK] Got a connection error for operation E0367CA861DAF5A9:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named
>   com.apple.cloudd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service
>   named com.apple.cloudd}

I know the reason as I am wrongly initialise CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation
Please check the following code and correct me:

```
 CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation  *operation = [[CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation alloc]initWithRecordZoneIDs:@[ recordZoneID ] optionsByRecordZoneID:@{@"Zone":recordZoneID,@"FetchRecordZoneChangesOptions":option}];
```

I need help on this part:

```
**@{@"Zone":recordZoneID,@"FetchRecordZoneChangesOptions":option}];**
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply create variable:

```
var serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? {

    guard let encoded = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)?.data(forKey: ServerChangeTokenKey) else {
        return nil
    }

    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encoded) as? CKServerChangeToken
}
```

And then init an object:

```
        let zone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "my_custom_zone_name")
        let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
        options.previousServerChangeToken = serverChangeToken

        let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: [zone.zoneID], optionsByRecordZoneID: [zone.zoneID: options])
```

Answer (score 2):

Even by using the right CKServerChangeToken, I was encountering this error because I didn't control the case where the array `changedZoneIDs` has 0 elements.

Strictly speaking, you need two separate CKServerChangeToken to access the database changes and the zoneChanges (let's say `databaseChangeToken` and `zoneChangeToken`). You can create them as Bartłomiej Semańczyk explains

-use recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock to get the zoneID of the changed zones
-use fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock to save the databaseChangeToken and to call the CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation where you use the zoneChangeToken, 
-each zone has its own changeToken so I ended up with this solution:

```
let operation = CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: databaseChangeToken)
var changedZoneIDs: [CKRecordZoneID] = []

operation.recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock = { (zoneID) in
    changedZoneIDs.append(zoneID)
}

operation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock = { (databaseToken, moreComing, error) in
{
    //manage moreComing
    //save databaseToken
    //manage error

    if changedZoneIDs.count > 0
    {
        var optionsByRecordZoneID = [CKRecordZoneID: CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions]()
        for zoneID in changedZoneIDs {
            let changeTokenData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "\(zoneID.zoneName) zoneChangeToken") as? Data // Read change token from disk
            var zoneChangeToken:CKServerChangeToken?

            if (changeTokenData != nil){
                zoneChangeToken = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: changeTokenData!)as! CKServerChangeToken?
            }
            let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
            options.previousServerChangeToken = zoneChangeToken
            optionsByRecordZoneID[zoneID] = options
        }
        let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: changedZoneIDs, optionsByRecordZoneID: optionsByRecordZoneID)

    // ...
    }
```

Comment: Eureka!  I missed the concept of the zoneToken and the databaseToken being different tokens.